What to add to s57objectclasses.csv to read missing inland S-57 layers?
I am working with S-57-files provided by Dutch Rijkswaterstaat, for example downloadable from here (publicly available). I'm trying to extract information from the layers with gdal (python).
The Inland charts have layers with OBJL attributes that denote feature types that do not seem to appear in s57objectclasses.csv:
bash-3.2$ ogrinfo 1R7YM004/1R7YM004.000 Generic |grep OBJL | uniq -c
Warning 1: Attributes BCNSHP ignored, not in expected schema.
No more warnings will be issued for this dataset.
Warning 1: Illegal feature attribute id (ATTF:ATTL[4]) of 17011
on feature FIDN=-115676329, FIDS=64091.
Skipping attribute. No more warnings will be issued.
   1 OBJL: Integer (5.0)
   4   OBJL (Integer) = 17028
  47   OBJL (Integer) = 17029
  10   OBJL (Integer) = 17032
  33   OBJL (Integer) = 17031
   2   OBJL (Integer) = 17067
bash-3.2$ 

As far as I understand, this means that the encoder used layers that are non-standard. I see in the s57objectclasses.csv that 17XXX layers are specific to inland waterways, but these particular layers are missing:
...
0,"###Codes in the 17xxx range come from past s57objectclasses_iw.csv (Inland Waterways)",,,,,,
17000,Anchor berth,achbrt,catach;clsdng;comctn;DATEND;DATSTA;NOBJNM;OBJNAM;PEREND;PERSTA;RADIUS;restrn;STATUS;,INFORM;NINFOM;NTXTDS;PICREP;SCAMIN;TXTDSC;updmsg;,SORDAT;SORIND;,G,Point;Area;
17001,Anchorage area,achare,catach;clsdng;comctn;DATEND;DATSTA;NOBJNM;OBJNAM;PEREND;PERSTA;restrn;STATUS;,INFORM;NINFOM;NTXTDS;PICREP;SCAMIN;TXTDSC;updmsg;,SORDAT;SORIND;,G,Point;Area;
...
17018,Navigational system of marks,m_nsys,marsys;ORIENT;,INFORM;NINFOM;NTXTDS;SCAMIN;TXTDSC;updmsg;,SORDAT;SORIND;,G,Area;
... <missing layers?> ...
17050,Notice mark,notmrk,catnmk;fnctnm;dirimp;disipd;disipu;disbk1;disbk2;addmrk;marsys;ORIENT;CONDTN;NOBJNM;OBJNAM;STATUS;,INFORM;NINFOM;NTXTDS;PICREP;SCAMIN;TXTDSC;updmsg;,SORDAT;SORIND;,G,Point;
17051,Waterway axis,wtwaxs,catccl;NOBJNM;OBJNAM;,INFORM;NINFOM;NTXTDS;PICREP;SCAMIN;TXTDSC;updmsg;,SORDAT;SORIND;,G,Line;

Am I supposed to add these objectclasses myself to the csv-file? How would I know which attributes to add for these particular features?
